# Queries with arguments in Android Studio - Room

Tags: java, android, database, android-asynctask, android-room

I want to make a Query to get all birds in a family and I'm not sure how to do it. I've done this so far but I feel like I'm missing something:

DAO:

```
@Query("Select * from bird WHERE family=:family")
public LiveData<List<Bird>> getBirdsFromFamily(String family);
```

Repository:

```
private LiveData<List<Bird>> allBirdsFromFamily;

private String family;

public BirdRepository(Application application){
    Database database = Database.getInstance(application);
    dao = database.dao();


    allBirdsFromFamily = dao.getBirdsFromFamily(family);
}


public LiveData<List<Bird>> getBirdsFromFamily(String family){
    return allBirdsFromFamily; 
}
```

View model:

```
private LiveData<List<Bird>> allBirdsFromFamily;

private String family;


public BirdViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    birdRepository = new BirdRepository(application);

    allBirdsFromFamily = birdRepository.getBirdsFromFamily(family);

}


public LiveData<List<Bird>> getAllBirdsFromFamily(String family)
{
    return allBirdsFromFamily;
}
```

I have a list of families and a list of birds.

When clicking on an item of the family list, I want to open a list with all the birds inside. I can get the String out of the item but nothing appears when I call the method.

```
    String family = intent.getStringExtra(AddEditFamilyActivity.EXTRA_FAMILY);

        birdViewModel.getAllBirdsFromFamily(family).observe(this, new Observer<List<Bird>>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Bird> birds) { //everytime something changes, the adaptater is updated
                //update the recycler view
                adapter.submitList(birds);
            }

        });
```

Comment: what issues are you having, we need more details

Comment: What's your issue exactly ? I've noticed a small error in your `ViewModel`, you don't need the variable in `getAllBirdsFromFamily` as it returns your `LiveData`, how did you manage the query in background ?

Comment: Your `family` string is probably null and should be `MutableLiveData<String>` switchMapped into the Dao Query method

Comment: @Biscuit I don't have any doInBackGround for this query, how should I do it ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that is what I thougt, but the debugger found the right String I wanted when clicking on the previous family item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with a factory - doInBackground wasn't necessary because it's only a "get" query :

DAO :

```
@Query("Select * from bird WHERE family=:family ORDER BY name")
public LiveData<List<Bird>> getBirdsFromFamily(String family);
```

Repository :

```
private LiveData<List<Bird>> allBirdsFromFamily;
private String family;

public BirdRepository(Application application){
    Database database = Database.getInstance(application);
    birdDao = database.dao();

    allBirdsFromFamily = birdDao.getBirdsFromFamily(family);
}


public LiveData<List<Bird>> getAllBirdsFromFamily(String family){
    return birdDao.getBirdsFromFamily(family);
}
```

ViewModel :

```
       private LiveData<List<Bird>> allBirdsFromFamily;
          private BirdRepository repository;

            public BirdViewModel(@NonNull Application application, String family ) {
                super(application);
                this.application = application;

                repository = new BirdRepository(application);
    allBirdsFromFamily = repository.getAllBirdsFromFamily(family);
            }    

        public LiveData<List<Bird>> getAllBirdsFromFamily(String family) { return repository.getAllBirdsFromFamily(family); }
```

ViewModelFactory :

```
    private Application mApplication;
    private String mfamily;

    public BirdViewModelFactory(@NonNull Application application, String family) {
        mApplication = application;
        mfamily = family;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new BirdViewModel(mApplication, mfamily);
    }
```

Activity :

```
     BirdViewModelFactory factory = new BirdViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), family);
     birdViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(BirdViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

As my comment is a bit long i'll make a post.

> I don't have any doInBackGround for this query, how should I do it ?

Yes, when you query to the database you want to avoid using the Main Thread for 2 reasons, the first one is because you'll get a crash from Android telling you not to do it. And the second is to let your user interact with your application while it do the work of getting the data.

In this [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) you can look at the samples and Codelabs and to learn how to make a call to database properly.